# addEventListener seems to trap my global variable

Tags: javascript, native, addeventlistener

I have a non-jquery script with an *addEventListener* on a buttonclick. This works fine the first run but I want it to **change "sendingurl" to some other value after the first click**. (the succesfull insert of form becomes an update form). However, even though sendingurl fills with the new id value, it doesnt change after the event is fired again. Instead by the second click it fires the newly created event tohether with the old one with the old value.

The resulting values in console.log:

1. 1st click: event "click" is fired with url: input.php
2. 2nd click:

   - event "click" is fired with url: input.php
   - event "click" is fired with url: update.php?io=items&id=693

So I want to get rid of the input being triggered after the first click. Does someone know how to solve this?

```js
var itemid = getHash();
ini(prepare); // using window.onload to execute


function prepare() {
  if (itemid) {
    // update
    var sendingurl = 'update.php?io=items&id=' + itemid;
  } else {
    // input
    var sendingurl = 'input.php';
  }

  // submitevent
  æ($("submitBtn"), 'click', function() {
    console.log("event \"click\" is fired with url: " + sendingurl);
    var json = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
    ajax(sendingurl, json, submittedInput);
  });
}


// callback function after ajax did his magic
function submittedInput(response) {
  if (response) {
    if (!itemid) {
      itemid = response;
      prepare();
    }
  } else {
    $("status").innerHTML = "something went wrong with the input";
  }
}

// function to add events without the use of jquery or prototype
function æ(el, evType, fn, useCapture) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.removeEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
    el.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
    return true;
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.detachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
    var r = el.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
    return r;
  } else {
    el['on' + evType] = fn;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time through, there is no event handler to remove and your anonymous function is added as an event handler. The anonymous function creates as closure, so the value of sendingurl is now "constant" no matter how the external sendingurl changes. That is why you are getting the old value.

The second time through, the event handler function being passed to removeEventListener is not yet tied to an event because the second anonymous function is not the same function as the anonymous function on the first pass. So no event handler is removed. You then add a second event with the new anonymous function with the revised value of sendingurl. That is why you are seeing both functions fire.

Convert your anonymous function to a normal function and use the normal function name instead.

Comment: yes I tried that after reading here on stackoverflow about not being able to remove an event that has anonymous functions, but after changing that... æ($("submitBtn"), 'click', submit(sendingurl));
...the event becomes 'broken'. It triggers right at document load.

Comment: You can't pass a parameter when you give a function name to ae. It should be ae($('#submitBtn'), 'click', submit); and then pick up sendingurl as a variable in scope.

Comment: I just logged in to comment that I removed the var and made it global instead. thnx for the help :) it works now.

Comment: Sorry I need to re-open this. It works because sendingurl gets changed but the problem of a double submit has stayed. I now get two update requests everytime I submit after the first submit (insert)

Comment: In your event handler (the anonymous function to ae) you need to prevent the default event behavior, which is to submit the form. So change the function to function(evt) and insert a evt.preventDefault() statement.

Comment: The functon is not anonymous anymore but for what it's worth I did what you suggested but nothing changed. The function is now: <code class="prettyprint"><!-- language: lang-js --> ` æ($("submitBtn"), 'click', submit);
 function submit(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
  var json = new FormData(document.forms[0]); // XHR 2 (not for IE 9 and lower or android browser 2.3 or opera mini
  ajax(sendingurl,json,submittedInput);    
 }`</code>

Comment: Do you have an updated code snippet that displays the error still occuring? BTW, your original Snippet has a JS error that keeps it from working: "getHash undefined".